# Contact Form with Php & Ajax Sending Partial Email

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have designed the following slick Form and using it with PhP & ajax to submit ... its working fine including sending email to the targeted email ID .. There are total Seven (07) fields which suppose to be filled by the visitor. the problem is that when Someone submit the form with all fields  I can only receive three (03) fields (Name, Email & Message).... the rest of the Four (04) fields (Phone,country,Budget & Select) are not showing in email... I am sure there must be some problem with my Php. Please tell me where I am mistaking in the following Php.

```
<?php

// Define some constants
define( "RECIPIENT_NAME", "John Smith" );
define( "RECIPIENT_EMAIL", "example@example.com" );
define( "EMAIL_SUBJECT", "Visitor Message" );

// Read the form values
$success = false;
$senderName = isset( $_POST['senderName'] ) ? preg_replace( "/[^\.\-\' a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $_POST['senderName'] ) : "";
$senderEmail = isset( $_POST['senderEmail'] ) ? preg_replace( "/[^\.\-\_\@a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $_POST['senderEmail'] ) : "";
$senderPhone = isset( $_POST['senderPhone'] ) ? preg_replace( "/[^\.\-\_\@a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $_POST['senderPhone'] ) : "";
$senderCountry = isset( $_POST['senderCountry'] ) ? preg_replace( "/[^\.\-\_\@a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $_POST['senderCountry'] ) : "";
$senderBudget = isset( $_POST['senderBudget'] ) ? preg_replace( "/[^\.\-\_\@a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $_POST['senderBudget'] ) : "";
$senderSelect = isset( $_POST['senderSelect'] ) ? preg_replace( "/[^\.\-\_\@a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $_POST['senderSelect'] ) : "";
$message = isset( $_POST['message'] ) ? preg_replace( "/(From:|To:|BCC:|CC:|Subject:|Content-Type:)/", "", $_POST['message'] ) : "";

// If all values exist, send the email
if ( $senderName && $senderEmail && $senderPhone && $senderCountry && $senderBudget && $senderSelect && $message ) {
  $recipient = RECIPIENT_NAME . " <" . RECIPIENT_EMAIL . ">";
  $headers = "From: " . $senderName . " <" . $senderEmail . ">";
  $success = mail( $recipient, EMAIL_SUBJECT, $message, $headers );
}

// Return an appropriate response to the browser
if ( isset($_GET["ajax"]) ) {
  echo $success ? "success" : "error";
} else {
?>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Thanks!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <?php if ( $success ) echo "<p>Thanks for sending your message! We'll get back to you shortly.</p>" ?>
  <?php if ( !$success ) echo "<p>There was a problem sending your message. Please try again.</p>" ?>
  <p>Click your browser's Back button to return to the page.</p>
  </body>
</html>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: **Too much code**. You need to do a better job of troubleshooting this yourself. We are *not* debuggers. You need **isolate the problem** and debug from there. If you're stuck provide a **clear explanation of what isn't working** with a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading **[ask]** a good question and **[the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)**.

Comment: Question Revised for better understanding ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not added phone, country, budget and select fields while mailing. Try this:

```
if ( $senderName && $senderEmail && $senderPhone && $senderCountry && $senderBudget && $senderSelect && $message ) {

    $msgToSend = "Name: ".$senderName."\r\n";
    $msgToSend .= "Email: ".$senderEmail."\r\n";
    $msgToSend .= "Phone: ".$senderPhone."\r\n";
    $msgToSend .= "Sender Country: ".$senderCountry."\r\n";
    $msgToSend .= "Sender Budget: ".$senderBudget."\r\n";
    $msgToSend .= "Sender Select: ".$senderSelect."\r\n";
    $msgToSend .= "Message: ".$message;

    $recipient = RECIPIENT_NAME . " <" . RECIPIENT_EMAIL . ">";
    $headers = "From: " . $senderName . " <" . $senderEmail . ">";
    $success = mail( $recipient, EMAIL_SUBJECT, $msgToSend, $headers );
}
```